# Looping through files in a folder to change formulas to values

Tags: loops, formula

I'm working on a macro that loops through all files in a folder, changes formulas that point to other workbooks to values, and saves and closes each file. I've merged two pieces of code from Ron de Bruin into the below macro. His code to break links and change to values works perfectly when it isn't in the loop but when I run this macro the files then don't have the info, they instead return "#N/A". What am I doing wrong?

```
Sub Formulas()

Const strSavePath As String = “MyFilePath"

    Dim MyPath As String, FilesInPath As String
    Dim MyFiles() As String, Fnum As Long
    Dim mybook As Workbook
    Dim CalcMode As Long
    Dim sh As Worksheet
    Dim ErrorYes As Boolean
    Dim Path1 As Range
    Set Path1 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Monthly Reporting").Range("E2")
    Dim WorkbookLinks As Variant
    Dim i As Long

MyPath = strSavePath & Path1 & "\"

'Add a slash at the end if the user forget it
If Right(MyPath, 1) <> "\" Then
    MyPath = MyPath & "\"
End If

'If there are no Excel files in the folder exit the sub
FilesInPath = Dir(MyPath & "*.xl*")
If FilesInPath = "" Then
    MsgBox "No files found"
    Exit Sub
End If

'Fill the array(myFiles)with the list of Excel files in the folder
Fnum = 0
Do While FilesInPath <> ""
    Fnum = Fnum + 1
    ReDim Preserve MyFiles(1 To Fnum)
    MyFiles(Fnum) = FilesInPath
    FilesInPath = Dir()
Loop

'Change ScreenUpdating, Calculation and EnableEvents
With Application
    CalcMode = .Calculation
    .Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    .ScreenUpdating = False
    .EnableEvents = False
End With

'Loop through all files in the array(myFiles)
If Fnum > 0 Then
    For Fnum = LBound(MyFiles) To UBound(MyFiles)
        Set mybook = Nothing
        On Error Resume Next
        Set mybook = Workbooks.Open(MyPath & MyFiles(Fnum))
        On Error GoTo 0

        If Not mybook Is Nothing Then

            'Change cell value(s) in one worksheet in mybook
             WorkbookLinks = mybook.LinkSources(Type:=xlLinkTypeExcelLinks)
If IsArray(WorkbookLinks) Then
    For i = LBound(WorkbookLinks) To UBound(WorkbookLinks)
        mybook.BreakLink _
                Name:=WorkbookLinks(i), _
                Type:=xlLinkTypeExcelLinks
    Next i
Else
    MsgBox "No Links to other workbooks"
    End If
     If Err.Number > 0 Then
                ErrorYes = True
                Err.Clear
                'Save and close mybook
                mybook.Close savechanges:=True
            End If
            On Error GoTo 0
        Else
            'Not possible to open the workbook
            ErrorYes = True
        End If

    Next Fnum
End If

If ErrorYes = True Then
    MsgBox "There are problems in one or more files, possible problem:" _
         & vbNewLine & "protected workbook/sheet or a sheet/range that not exist"
End If

'Restore ScreenUpdating, Calculation and EnableEvents
With Application
    .ScreenUpdating = True
    .EnableEvents = True
    .Calculation = CalcMode
End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Is this a `vba` script?

Comment: @dan1st Yes that's right